# how to convert EFM32LG reference manual setting into C setting in Simplisity studio

Tags: embedded, uart

bellow we have USARTn_FRAME table .
inside of it some of its properties tables.
Also i tried to look at the functions that control these properties from the link bellow,
How do i define in simplisity studio with code an object with 8 data bits and Parity 2(even)?
Thanks.
https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32lg/html/structUSART__InitAsync__TypeDef.html#af8b618c4bebd42dd748eb00a39a05ee2
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you done/tried so far ? Please consider sharing a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have givien an exact place from the manual and the value i need for the functionality
i also shown quote from software manual.
its basicly doing P[add]=8 in C
i am asking for this thing

Comment: there are several way to do this. Without example we do not know your level of knowledge. Do you use the SDK or not ? Do you have experience with it ? Have you not understood some defines or do you ask for guidance or for the whole solution ?
I did some minimal answer but without example I'm not certain this is what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You have too look into file `em_usart.h` for the structure `USART_InitAsync_TypeDef` and/or `USART_InitSync_TypeDef`.

```
USART_InitAsync_TypeDef var = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT; 
//var.databits = usartDatabits8; //commented out because this is already in default
var.parity = usartEvenParity;
```

Comment: Hello Juliel you have defined var variable type USART_InitSync_TypeDef  to define the parity property from the usart_frame.
What about other proprties from the ROUTING register.
do i need to define a new variable for that? or show i dtay with var?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445 I answered exactly the question you asked. Please kindly have a look at [Siliconlabs peripheral examples](https://github.com/SiliconLabs/peripheral_examples) and then if you have any issue with the code produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)